# Storing an array of objects in external JSON file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, webstorm, data-storage

I have an array of objects in my javascript code that I would like to store as an external JSON file, more specifically in Webstorm's package.json. How can I achieve that? All the answers I find are related to the opposite - getting data from an external JSON file.

Here's the example of javascript array:

```js
var questions = [{
        question: "Question1",
        choices: ["Choice1", "Choice2", "Choice3", "Choice4"],
        corAnswer: 0
    }, {
        question: "Questions2",
        choices: ["Choice1", "Choice2", "Choice3", "Choice4"],
        corAnswer: 1
    }, {
        question: "Question3",
        choices: ["Choice1", "Choice2", "Choice3", "Choice4"],
        corAnswer: 3
    }];
```

I guess the first thing to do would be JSON.stringify, but how do I then store it in package.json?

Comment: Do you want to store a JSON string inside a JSON file, or do you want to manipulate a JSON file to have new data?

Comment: You can't write files to disk with JavaScript if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @tadman, more like the second option.

Comment: @Jonathan I meant that I wanted to store it separately from the JS code and then just link it in the document, the same way as you use external css file, for example.

Comment: So, what's stopping you from doing so?

Comment: @Jonathan I was thinking that I can't just copy paste my code into an external file? I mean the syntax between JS and JSON is a bit different and if I have a large array I'll need to fix it all manually.

Comment: @Clarity JSON.stringify should use only valid JSON, complete with quote marks. You can also write `JSON.stringify(myObj, null, true)` which should print it with proper spacing, to make it easier to change later.

Comment: @Katana314 I just used `JSON.stringify` on my array and the output was the same as for `JSON.stringify(myObj, null, true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write to files via Javascript, as others have said, but if you just want to store JSON objects in a different file and don't need to change the files, just throw them in a .js file and call that file in script tags before you call your main JS file. As long as it's in the global scope, the questions object will be available to methods in other files.

Comment: Damn, it took me a while to realise that package.json is used for other purposes in webstorm and that I actually needed an external .js file...

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I used `console.log` on the result of `JSON.stringify` and then copy/pasted the contents to an external json file...

Comment: well that's one way to do it :P